# ExtJs Model Proxy vs. Store Proxy

Tags: extjs, model, extjs4, store, restful-authentication

OK, I'm stuck on what should be a basic task in ExtJs.  I'm writing a simple login script that sends a user name and password combination to a RESTful web service and receives a GUID if the credentials are correct.

My question is, do I use a Model Proxy or a Store Proxy?

To my understanding, Models represent a single record, whereas Stores are for handling sets of data containing more than one record.  If this is correct then it would seem that a Model proxy is the way to go.

Following Sencha's documentation at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model the code would look something like this:

```
Ext.define('AuthenticationModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['username', 'password'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : '/authentication'
    }
});

//get a reference to the authentication model class
var AuthenticationModel = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('AuthenticationModel');
```

So far everything is OK, until the next step:

```
//Use the configured RestProxy to make a GET request
AuthenticationModel.load('???', {
    success: function(session) {
        console.log('Login successful');
    }
});
```

The load() method for the Model class is a static call expecting a single unique identifier.  Logins typically depend upon two factors, username and password.

So it appears Store proxies are the only way to validate someone's username and password credential combination in ExtJS.  Can someone verify and explain?  Any help to understand this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to know the following:

> The store will use it's own proxy if you configured one for this
>   instance and if not he takes the proxy from the model.

So you can easily go with two proxy configurations to enable the multi-CRUD operations on the store and the single-CRUD operations on the Models. Note the the static load method of the Model expects the model `id` because it is supposed to load a model by just one Id (yes, composite keys are not supported). You will also have to fetch the model instance in the callback (As you did).

**Back to your Username/password problem**

You may apply your session Model with a custom 'loadSession' method

```
loadSession: function(username,password, config) {
    config = Ext.apply({}, config);
    config = Ext.applyIf(config, {
        action: 'read',
        username: username,
        password: password
    });

    var operation  = new Ext.data.Operation(config),
        scope      = config.scope || this,
        callback;

    callback = function(operation) {
        var record = null,
            success = operation.wasSuccessful();

        if (success) {
            record = operation.getRecords()[0];
            // If the server didn't set the id, do it here
            if (!record.hasId()) {
                record.setId(username); // take care to apply the write ID here!!!
            }
            Ext.callback(config.success, scope, [record, operation]);
        } else {
            Ext.callback(config.failure, scope, [record, operation]);
        }
        Ext.callback(config.callback, scope, [record, operation, success]);
    };

    this.getProxy().read(operation, callback, this);
}
```

Now call this instead of load.

Answer (score 2):

I found it in the documentation of sencha App Architecture Part 2

**Use proxies for models:**

> It is generally good practice to do this as it allows you to load and
>   save instances of this model without needing a store. Also, when
>   multiple stores use this same model, you don’t have to redefine your
>   proxy on each one of them.

**Use proxies for stores:**

> In Ext JS 4, multiple stores can use the same data model, even if the
>   stores will load their data from different sources. In our example,
>   the Station model will be used by the SearchResults and the Stations
>   store, both loading the data from a different location. One returns
>   search results, the other returns the user’s favorite stations. To
>   achieve this, one of our stores will need to override the proxy
>   defined on the model.